# How can i copy the txtusername.text from form1 and when form2 load it will automatically set in txtusername in vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Here is the code for Form2:

```
Private sub regularupdate_load (sender As system.object, e as system..eventargs) handles maybase.Load

Txtusername.text = Form1.txtusername.Text

End sub
```

Comment: `Txtusername.text = Form1.txtusername.Text` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with saving text of textbox in a Module. So in your solution explorer, right click and click choose Add => Module... Then choose a name for your module. When, in your module create a public string like this:

```
Public UserNameSaved As String
```

Then and form1 closing write:

```
UserNameSaved = txtusername.Text
```

and on form2 load:

```
Txtusername.Text = UserNameSaved
```